# Trying to launch fragment inside actionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I have checked numbers of solutions on how to launch my fragment but nothing has worked so far. I appreciate any help I can get

*What I want is to get the content inside the fragment to show.*

I have 2 tabs that works but fragment inside each tab doesn´t show it content because the fragment is never lunched. Which is weird becouse fragment extende actionBarActivity. But if I make the mainActivity extende fragmentActivity works but then my tabs don't.

*Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());* Seems to not do the trick

Theme in androidManifest 
*android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"*

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import is.at.work.lottostokkur.R;
import is.at.work.lottostokkur.adapter.TabPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.addOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        }
    };
    //Add New Tab
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Lottó").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("About").setTabListener(tabListener));
}
}
```

And my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lottoId"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the fragment I'm trying to launch

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import is.at.work.lottostokkur.R;

public class LottoFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.
                inflate(R.layout.lotto, container, false);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("iOS");

        return view;
    }
}
```

My adapter

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                //Fragement for Lotto Tab
                return new LottoFragment();
            case 1:
                //Fragment for About Tab
                return new AboutFragment();
         }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
        public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2; //No of Tabs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

> I can't see the line that you set adapter to `ViewPager`
>
> in your case you should add following:
>
> ```
> Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
> ```

First of all, I would recommend using `AppCompatActivity` since the others are depreciated.

And also I recommend you not to use `actionbar.setNavigationMode()` method because it is depreciated too.

you have a lot of other options to achive the tab navigation.

Comment: At some point in my hack i have deleted that line, wtf.. I would give you 10x thumps up if I could. Thank you!